# How can I create a bridge between a solo chain created with substrate and Ethereum blockchain?

Tags: ethereum, token, bridge

Is there a tool offered by the substrate ecosystem that I can use, that can help me create a bridge between a solochain created with substrate and Ethereum blockchain? Specifically, I want to transfer between native tokens in the solo chain and wrapped tokens in the Ethereum blockchain. If there is no native tool, what is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Any parachain in Polkadot could benefit from BridgeHub systemchain, though in your case being a solo-chain I think you will want to look for solutions like https://github.com/ChainSafe/chainbridge-core for instance.
Depending on the features your solo-chain has you could be looking to deploy other flavors of bridges.